# CSS for multiple top fixed headers OR PHP browser

Tags: php, html, css

I am creating php browser it work well but for top fixed headers it is not working i.e. top both headers are opervlapping.

`<div style="color:#00AAFF; position:fixed; top:0; width:100%;"><input type="text" value="URL"/></div>`

```
<div style="color:#00AAFF; position:fixed; top:0; width:100%;"><?php curl function for opening url ?></div>
```

Comment: The above code is working fine. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Lbjdgy8o/)

Comment: check it it is not working (include 2 div also)
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lbjdgy8o/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<body style="min-height:1200px;">

<div style="color:#00AAFF; position:fixed; top:0; width:100%;">  
<input type="text" value="URL"/>
 </div>
<div style="color:#00AAFF; position:fixed; top:20px; width:100%;">
 hello<?php curl function for opening url ?>
 </div>
```

Please use css class and div to make more appropriate.